# What is the Difference between the following three statements?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I was doing a question in which we have to arrange certain different objects(Let's say $r$) with the following three different Conditions.Note that they are three different questions.

- No two of the $m$ objects are together $(m\le r)$
- All the $m$ objects should not be together.
- $m$ objects should not be together.

By $2^{nd}$ condition I understand that all of the $m$ should not be together. In my book $3^{rd}$ statement is the combination of $2^{nd}$ statement and the condition that some of the objects can be together.

So,what does all these statements mean?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "no two of the $m$ objects are together", it may also be understood as "between every two objects there is another one".

Regarding "all the objects are not together", it may be understood as "at least two objects have another one between them".